# Entity Framework MVC Slow Page Loads

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a web application running on Windows Azure.
It is built with ASP.Net 4.0, MVC 3, Entity Framework 4.1, SQL Server 2008 using the Repository pattern.

The app was performing very well until recently. Most of our customers have a few hundred rows of data but one of them is starting to reach 2000+. This has dramatically slowed their page load times (15 - 20 secs on some pages).

We just started using MiniProfiler which indicates we have a very chatty app- with duplicate SQL calls.

In an effort to give as much detail as possible and to figure out how we can do things better, I'll explain some of the stuff are doing.

We have a base controller that has two protected objects (CurrentUser and CurrentCompany). We use these quite a bit in our Actions, but it hits the DB each time. So, I am assuming we need to store these objects in session the first time. Is there a big overhead in lumping around these objects? What about accessing their relationships later (CurrentCompany.Offices.First(), etc)?

We get the data for each page based on these objects: selecting, ordering, filtering their relationships, for instance:

```
CurrentCompany.Employees.Where(r => r.StatusId = Enums.Statuses.Active);
```

Here 'CurrentCompany.Employees' returns an EntityCollection but the Where changes it to IEnumerable. I heard that IQueryable is the way to go?

I have also read that EF is great to get things up and running quickly but you must do some tweaking to make sure it performs well with lots of data. From what I have read, it will bring back the entire row even if you only asked for 2 columns?

So, with all that in mind- can someone point out what I should be doing to make this scale for bigger clients. 2000+ rows is not that much after all. Should we be using views/stored procs?

There are plently of resources out there explaining how to get EF setup with basic selects, etc- but nothing really one scalling it once the data set gets bigger.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Brian

Comment: Do you need to load the related object every time or could you lazy load them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: Is your database indexed properly?

Comment: like Bob The Janitor say i would try eager loading. lazyloading gone hit the database for each post while eager loading gone do it in one request. It made all the difference for my project, i had one situation just like this.

Comment: Have you used caching where necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the comments- I have not looked at caching or db indexes just yet- I had thought this was a solution for when you are dealing with massive amounts of data...I may be wrong but I thought that it should be straightforward enough to bring back 2000 rows....I think the problem is more fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much eager loading are you doing?  That was one thing we found to be a major performance hit, to solve it we started caching the properties using [Entlib Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647280.aspx)
and then merging them into the object from cache vs getting them from the DB

Comment: Hi Bob. We are doing lazy loading. Am I correct to say that if my code gets a list of all Employees and sends it to a view- will accessing any relationship (i.e. Employee.Hours) result in an extra call to the database? I set lazy loading to false and exceptions were thrown all over the code. I realise that I need to use the Include() function to call in the required relationships but this makes my code messy when using the Repository Pattern. Is there a neat way of achieving this? Anyway, after testing the page with Lazy Loading off, there are fewer db calls but overall the page is still slow.

Comment: yes, using lazy loading will do that, if it's still slow after turning off lazy load some things to look at, first what is the query performance like?  use Sql profiler to see what the calls are then run them in management studio, see if it's sql or the app that is being slow

Comment: Bob...you are correct, lazy loading is the problem. My test previously was incorrect. My only question is how did you go about implementing this? Our entire app is based on Lazy Loading which is great until a user has 2000 employees and retrieving them takes 2001 SQL calls! Anyway, did you guys turn it off by default or did you leave it on but eager load where neccessary? I dont want to turn the source code upside down!

Comment: we eager loaded when we needed to, and then mapped the results to dlt objects in the repository.  A simple refactor would be to update your repository to return List<> vs. Queriable<> and it should solve a lot of the problems you are having

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough the clue might be in the 2000 rows. SQL changes the way it accesses data when the choice passes 0.1%  of the dataset. You do not say if you have appropriate indexes on the tables. 
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-indexes-the-basics
may help
If you run SQL managment studio then there is a missing index feature
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345524.aspx

HTH

also here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/19/10051969.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ian. There are no indexes in the database. Maybe this is naive of me, but I thought that indexes would be needed when you are talking about large amounts of data...not a few thousand rows? I think the app should be comfortable bringing back 2000 rows and maybe there was something else at fault. I'll listen to other comments before trying indexes.

Comment: Well, there should always be a clustered index: basically a table is a heap until it has a clustered index. There is no overhead in a clustered index because it simply determines the order the rows are stored “on disk”. If there is no clustered index then SQL has no choice but to read all records in the table to determine which ones are appropriate to return. A clustered index (especially a covering one  Google covering index for more) will allow the SQL engine just to read the index only and only the rows to be returned.

Comment: This is a topic that takes a book. http://www.insidesqlserver.com/thebooks.html Kalen Delany is one of the top 2 or 3 experts. There are versions for 2012 and  azure http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/11/02/10084745.aspx http://sqlblog.com/blogs. also /kalen_delaney/archive/2010/11/02/whitepaper-inside-sql-azure.aspx I'd say creating an index is a one line statement, easy to create, easy to drop. Best if the choice is good though.

Comment: Thanks Ian! Lazy Loading was the problem in this instance, but you are correct- we need indexes also!

Comment: No problem, the niceties of SQL tend not to be the natural playing ground of the c dev.

Answer (score 0):

based on my own experience, EF is very slow because it uses LINQ (very slow)
i had a personnal web site (a home page which displays multiple kinds of data, so i had to do multiple requests to the database server in LINQ). it was very slow, i tried to tweak the EF .edmx with lazy loading options, etc......the only solution i found was to get rid of linq, and rewrite it in ado.net, it takes more time to code, but i get rid of speed problems.....
LINQ requests must be translated to sql, there a lot of steps before it gets to the database, and when it gets data (select*), it translates it to a list of object models in EF.
thanks you

Comment: Linq is not inherantly slow if used correctly. Of course if you return "all rows" and "all columns" then you are shuffing a large ammount of data which is slow. However if you use LINQ with paramaterised queries the hard data typing has much to reccommend it.