# threadpool starvation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asynchronous, sqlcommand

My problem relates to an aspx.net 4.0 web server blocking under increased load. By blocking
I mean the request is send by the client but the response is returned after ~45 seconds. This is reproducable in development and production environment. This 45 seconds seem to be constant and I measured this both on the client and in the aspx page between calling the Constructor() and `void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)`.
I use both several SqlDataSources and custom made controls utilising 6 `SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader(...)` in total on one page. I can eliminate the problem if I deactivate the controls with the `BeginExecuteReader` / `EndExecuteReader` pattern. So I assume that eventually one of the BeginExecute calls is blocked until a thread becomes available in the ThreadPool.

I print debug messages and recognized a pattern where always a bunch of thread exit messages is printed just befor the blocked request is returned:

> The thread 'GetMolFileAsync' (0x1ba4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 'GetMolFileAsync' (0x27d0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread '' (0x23c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 'GetCompoundDepositionInfo' (0x1e88) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> The thread 'GetMolFileAsync' (0x2758) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>
> 0x43  27/07/2012 15:09:42 45 ==> **blocked thread took 45 seconds**
>
> 0x5F  27/07/2012 15:10:27 0 ==> **normal behaviour, processed in some miliseconds**
>
> ...

This is the method to start a request to the data base

```
public static IAsyncResult GetCompoundDepositionInfoAsync(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        GetCompoundVersionInfoAsyncParameters parameters = (GetCompoundVersionInfoAsyncParameters)state;
        IAsyncResult res = null;

        parameters.cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("www.GetCompoundDepositionInfo", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(parameters.connectionstring));
        parameters.cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        parameters.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompoundID", parameters.CompoundID);
        try
        {
            parameters.cmd.Connection.Open();
            res = parameters.cmd.BeginExecuteReader(callback, parameters, System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (parameters.cmd.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                parameters.cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
            throw new Exception("Exception in calling GetCompoundDepositionInfoAsync()", ex);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

this is the callback function

```
public void GetCompoundDepositionInfoCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        gmdTools.GmdCompound.GetCompoundVersionInfoAsyncParameters param = (gmdTools.GmdCompound.GetCompoundVersionInfoAsyncParameters)result.AsyncState;

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "GetCompoundDepositionInfo";
        using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = param.cmd)
        using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.EndExecuteReader(result))
        {
            try
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    lblDeposited.Text = string.Concat("at ", reader.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString(), " by ", reader.GetString(1));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the code to glue them together...

```
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(
                new BeginEventHandler(gmdTools.GmdCompound.GetCompoundLastChangeInfoAsync)
                , new EndEventHandler(GetCompoundLastChangeInfoCallback)
                , new EndEventHandler(GetCompoundInfoAsyncTimeout)
                , new gmdTools.GmdCompound.GetCompoundVersionInfoAsyncParameters()
                {
                    connectionstring = Properties.Settings.Default.GmdConnectionString,
                    CompoundID = CompoundId,
                }, true
            ));
```

As I already spent hours looking at this code I would be appreciate any feedback.

**UPDATE**
This 45 seconds are reasoned by the default `Page.AsyncTimeout` and can be changed to 10 seconds using the `Async="true" AsyncTimeout="10"` statements. Although I improved the overall performance of the site very much by adding appropiate indexes, very ocasionally the client has to wait this amount of time, before the server sends the response. In this cases no `AsyncTimeout` handler is called. I assume that the page registers all async operations but eventually does not recognise that some of the async operations completed successfully and hence waits the AsyncTimeout seconds before rendering the page. Any comments on that?

Comment: Looks like blocking on the database. I suggest you monitor database activity/use SQL Profiler to find out what is happening on the database.

Comment: Are you sure the database queries aren't the culprit here? The fact that the timing is consistently the same across a number of clients suggests the common factor may be the database.

Comment: @ShellShock: Thank you for commenting my question! Given your experience, what events in the SQL profiler do you suggest to track this blocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably the database, given the choice or rows the query returns, is it choosing more or less than one in a thousand? MS SQL will change the way it operates when the choice goes through 1 in 1000 rows returned. If you run the query using SQL profiler, do you get a table scan? If you run the built in sp for determining missing indexes, does it return requests for indexes on these tables? Are your statistics up to date? On clue to this is that a restored backup runs the query quickly, because when you restore a backup, the statisitcs are updated. Is there a clustered index on (all/each) of your tables?

Also this answer might be relevant [Entity Framework MVC Slow Page Loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415070/entity-framework-mvc-slow-page-loads/10415288#10415288)

Comment: I optimised some of the queries by adding appropiate indexes which led to an overall improvement. However, the blocking is still happening some times. On the other hand I now use `System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out AvailableWorkerThreads, out AvailablePortThreads)` and `System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out MaxWorkerThreads, out MaxPortThreads)` to verify that I have plenty of 2,400 PortThreads and 2,379 WorkerThreads available. Thank you all for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [async=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) property in the connectionstring. This is required for real asynchrnous operations using the SqlClient.
If possible can you try this on .Net 4.5 with the Task async feature with code like below.

```
public async Task GetCompoundDepositionInfoAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    parameters.cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("www.GetCompoundDepositionInfo", new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(parameters.connectionstring));
    parameters.cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    parameters.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompoundID", parameters.CompoundID);
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(parameters.connectionstring))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            if (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
            {
                lblDeposited.Text = string.Concat("at ", reader.GetDateTime(0).ToShortDateString(), " by ",     reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in page_load()

```
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetCompoundDepositionInfoAsync));
```

Comment: I do use `async=true` in the connection string.